# include google maps geocoder in reactjs

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

Hello I have the following Code in regular js/html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize()
  {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    ...
  }
</script>
```

Now I want to transfer it to a react component.

```
export default class Map extends Component {
   initialize() {
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
          ....
   }
   render(){
         .....
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work, since I don't know how to include the google maps api into my component.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post your error logs? Also check this sample from [GitHub](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps).

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem ?